# GAAP or non-GAAP numbers in nasdaq.com?

Tags: stocks, investing, corporate-earnings

As can be seen [here on nasdaq.com](http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/msft) Microsoft's EPS for the last quarter was supposedly $0.69. According to [this website](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2016-07-19/microsoft-misses-gaap-revenue-eps-beats-non-gaap-after-using-lower-tax-rate-stock-so) MSFT Non-GAAP EPS was $0.69 and GAAP EPS was only $0.39. This means that NASDAQ website uses non-GAAP EPS numbers for Microsoft.

However, for other companies that I manually checked on nasdaq.com it seems that NASDAQ consistently uses GAAP numbers. These are typically (always?) lower than non-GAAP numbers.

1. First of all, am I misinterpreting MSFT earnings?
2. Who enters those numbers in the system? Is microsoft granted direct access to the nasdaq.com system or did someone from nasdaq.com read MSFT earning's report and manually entered those numbers?
3. How come nasdaq.com for one company (e.g. AAPL) is using GAAP EPS and for a different company (e.g. MSFT) is using non-GAAP EPS numbers? Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're interpreting things correctly, at least at a high level. Those numbers come from the 10Q filing and investor summary from Microsoft, but are provided to NASDAQ by Zacks Investment Research, as noted on the main page you linked to.  That's a big investment data firm.

I'm not sure why they reported non-GAAP Microsoft numbers and not, say, AAPL numbers; it's possible they felt the non-GAAP numbers reflect things better (or have in the past) for some material reason, or it's possible they made a typo, though the last three quarters at least all used non-GAAP numbers for MSFT.  MSFT indicates that the difference in GAAP and non-GAAP revenue is primarily deferred revenue (from Windows and Halo).

I did confirm that the SEC filing for MSFT does include the GAAP number, not the non-GAAP number (as you'd expect).

I will also note that it looks like the 10Q is not the only source of information.  Look at ORCL for example: they had in the March 2016 report (period ending 2/29/16) revenues of .50/share GAAP / .64/share non-GAAP.  But the NASDAQ page indicates .59/share for that quarter.

My suspicion is that the investment data firm (Zack's) does additional work and includes certain numbers they feel belong in the revenue stream but are not in the GAAP numbers.  Perhaps MS (and Oracle) have more of those - such as deferred software revenues (AAPL has relatively little of that, as most of their profit is hardware).